# how to view memory for " char *str = "yoo"; "

Tags: c

it is said...

```
char *str = "yoo";
```

looks like this in the memory :

```
--------------------------------------------
| 'y' | 'o' | 'o' | '\0' | 'z' | 'b' | 't' | ...
--------------------------------------------
```

how to view "yoo" in memory like in above example ?

what type of tools have been used to print the above artwork ?

> I would like to examine the memory after i write a string to it. to
>   see what it looks like in the memory.

Comment: keyboard & hands in that case, probably

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `str + i` yields a pointer to the `i`th byte of the string which you can examine.

Comment: Memory access after `'\0'` probably is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, you don't write a string to memory there. You just have a pointer that points to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you mean, but perhaps some fancy printing can help:

```
for(i=0; i < MEM_SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("--------------");
    printf("| 0x%X |%x|\n ",&(str+i),*(str+i));
}
```

Of course, you may want to make sure the number of digits stays somewhat constant so everything lines up neatly and also account for different size (perhaps you want to go trough the memory a word or a double word at a time).

Comment: 1.) you want `(str+i)` instead o `&(str+i)`; 2.) to print an address (the value of a `void*`) use the `p` conversion specifier, else the code provokes Undefined Behaviour: `printf("| %p |%x|\n ", (void*)(str+i), *(str+i));` or even more straight forward: `printf("| %p |%x|\n ", &str[i], str[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Since it is necessary to manage the number of output characters for such output, creating a dynamic string (like StringBuffer in java) makes the work easier.

The following is a simple implementation example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct StringBuffer {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;
    char *str;
} SB;
void *mallocWithCheck(size_t size, const char *mes){
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if(!p){
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed, %s.\n", mes);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}
void *reallocWithCheck(void *p, size_t size, const char *mes){
    void *ret = realloc(p, size);
    if(!ret){
        free(p);
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed, %s.\n", mes);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ret;
}
SB *SB_makeWithInitSize(size_t size){
    SB *sb = mallocWithCheck(sizeof(*sb), __func__);
    sb->str = mallocWithCheck(sb->capacity = size, __func__);
    sb->length = 0;
    return sb;
}
void SB_drop(SB *sb){
    free(sb->str);
    free(sb);
}
void SB_appendChar(SB *sb, char ch){
    if(sb->length == sb->capacity){
        sb->str = reallocWithCheck(sb->str, sb->capacity *= 2, __func__);
    }
    sb->str[sb->length++] = ch;
}
void SB_appendCString(SB *sb, char *s){
    while(*s)
        SB_appendChar(sb, *s++);
}
void SB_init(SB *sb){
    sb->length = 0;
}
char *SB_toString(SB *sb){
    SB_appendChar(sb, 0);
    sb->length--;
    return sb->str;
}

void memdmp(const void *p, size_t size, size_t width){
    const unsigned char *c = p;
    SB *sb = SB_makeWithInitSize(size * 6);
    char buff[16];

    while(size){
        SB_init(sb);
        for(; size; --size, ++c){
            int field_size;
            if(*c == '\'' || *c == '\\')
                field_size = sprintf(buff, "| '\\%c' ", *c);
            else if(isprint(*c))
                field_size = sprintf(buff, "| '%c' ", *c);
            else
                field_size = sprintf(buff, "| '\\%#o' ", *c);
            if(field_size + sb->length > width-2)
                break;
            SB_appendCString(sb, buff);
        }
        SB_appendChar(sb, '|');
        char *middle = SB_toString(sb);
        size_t len = sb->length;
        //print upper part
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            putchar('-');
        //print middle part
        printf("\n%s\n", middle);
        //print bottom part
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            putchar('-');
        puts("");
    }
    SB_drop(sb);
}

int main(void){
    const char str[] = "yoo";
    const int width = 80;
    char buff[16];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); ++i)
        buff[i] = rand() % 256;
    memcpy(buff, str, sizeof str);
    memdmp(buff, sizeof buff, width);
}
```

Example of execution:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 'y' | 'o' | 'o' | '\0' | '\0341' | 'l' | '\0326' | '\0256' | 'R' | '\0220' |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
| 'I' | '\0361' | '\0361' | '\0273' | '\0351' | '\0353' |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "*a simple implementation*" well ... ;->